# Multiple GoTrueClient instances detected in the same browser context

Tags: reactjs, next.js, supabase

I'm creating a project with nextjs and supabase.

For an unknown reason, I'm getting the following warning in the console:

> Multiple GoTrueClient instances detected in the same browser context.
> It is not  an error, but this should be avoided as it may produce
> undefined behavior when  used concurrently under the same storage key.

I can't seem to find what could be causing this,

This is how I initiate the supabase instance in _app.tsx:

```js
export default function App({
  Component,
  pageProps,
}: AppProps<{ initialSession: Session }>) {
  const [supabaseClient] = useState(() => createBrowserSupabaseClient());

  return (
    <>
      <style jsx global>
        {`
          :root {
            --font-inter: ${inter.style.fontFamily};
          }
        `}
      </style>
      <SessionContextProvider
        supabaseClient={supabaseClient}
        initialSession={pageProps.initialSession}
      >
        <ChakraProvider theme={theme}>
          <Layout>
            <Component {...pageProps} />
          </Layout>
        </ChakraProvider>
      </SessionContextProvider>
    </>
  );
}
```

and this is how I consume the instance in components:

```js
const ForgotPassword = () => {
  const toast = useToast();
  const supabase = useSupabaseClient();
...
}
```

Have you ever had an issue like that and can help me understand what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why I was getting this error is because I had to downgrade the `auth-helpers-nextjs` from 0.7.x to 0.6.x to support no email confirmation when registering,

Version 0.7.x automatically returns singleton object for `createPagesBrowserClient`

With version 0.6.x `createBrowserSupabaseClient` always return new object rather then singleton,

With reactStrictMode enabled with react 18 the page will render twice, causing the error of Multiple GoTrueClients.

How I fixed it is by creating a new object with singleton instance of Supabase Client:

```js
import { createBrowserSupabaseClient } from "@supabase/auth-helpers-nextjs";

const SupabaseClient = {
  instance: createBrowserSupabaseClient(),
};

export type SupabaseClientType = typeof SupabaseClient;

Object.freeze(SupabaseClient);

export { SupabaseClient };
```

And then consume it in the _app.tsx:

```js
const [supabaseClient] = useState(() => SupabaseClient.instance);
```

Now the warning should be gone.

Answer (score 1):

Only run `createClient` once, then return that instance on subsequent executions

---

Change your code from

```
import { createClient } from '@supabase/supabase-js';

const supabase = () => createClient(process.env.SUPABASE_URL, process.env.SUPABASE_KEY);

export default supabase;
```

to

```
import { createClient } from '@supabase/supabase-js';

const client = createClient(process.env.SUPABASE_URL, process.env.SUPABASE_KEY);

const supabase = () => client;

export default supabase;
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure this is solving my case as I'm not using create client at all

Comment: Can you try using `createClient` instead?

Answer (score 0):

Better yet with typescript and auth headers

```html
import { createClient } from "@supabase/supabase-js";
import { Database } from "@lib/database.types";

const options = {
  auth: {
    localStorage: true,
    autoRefreshToken: true,
    persistSession: true,
    detectSessionInUrl: true,
  },
};

const supabaseUrl = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SUPABASE_URL;
const supabaseKey = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SUPABASE_ANON_KEY;

const client = createClient<Database>(supabaseUrl, supabaseKey, options);

const supabase = () => client;

export default supabase;
```

Answer (score 0):

Turning the "createBrowserClient" into a singleton fixed it for me (but don't do that for the serverClient).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to make works this

Create the **supabase.tsx** file  if you are using **vite** or .js if you are using CRA, and put this:

```
import { createClient } from '@supabase/supabase-js';

const client = createClient(import.meta.env.VITE_SUPABASE_URL, 
import.meta.env.VITE_SUPABASE_ANON);

const supabase = () => client;

export default supabase;
```

Now, imports the supabase file in the login component

```
import supabase from "../supabase"

const handleSubmit = async (e: React.FormEvent) => {
e.preventDefault()
let { data, error } = await 
supabase().auth.signInWithPassword({ email, password })
if (error) {
  console.log(error.message)
} else {
  console.log(data)
}
}
```

I hope this help you